# Cypress and select2 jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, cypress

How to use cypress with [select2](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options) 
I Have some problem while using Select2 Jquery Plugin and cypress
My html

```
<div class="form__polozka-hodnota"><select name="client_type" data-cy="typ_klienta" data-dep="" class="form-control"
    id="frm-vehicleInsurance-form-client_type" required
    data-nette-rules='[{"op":":filled","msg":"Vyberte: Typ klienta"}]'>
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="1">Fyzická osoba</option>
    <option value="2">Právnická osoba</option>
</select></div>
```

Cypress:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=typ_klienta]').select('Fyzická osoba').should('have.value', '1')
```

CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because this element:

...

is being covered by another element:

...

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.

https://on.cypress.io/element-cannot-be-interacted-with

Output console:

```
$('[data-cy="typ_klienta"]')
```

Object { 0: select#frm-vehicleInsurance-form-client_type.form-control.select2-hidden-accessible, length: 1, prevObject: {…} }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started a recipe, for now showing how to select a single value (your use case), see https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/pull/439

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile there is a very good and detailed blogpost about cypress and select2, see https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/03/20/working-with-select-elements-and-select2-widgets-in-cypress/

In my project I can now simply use "force:true" to select a value in my select2

`cy.get('[data-cy=typ_klienta]').select('Fyzická osoba', {force: true})`